# how to pass multiple values using single textbox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am doing vb.net programming. In that, I am using one textbox, one gridview and one button. Now, I want to pass queries into the textbox and when clicking on button, I want to display the result into the datagridview.

i.e suppose i am passing selection query and clicking on button at that time i want to display the table data into the datagridview.

Comment: Just like me, everybody else in SO would like to help you. But first let us know what have you tried till now.?? If you haven't tried anything yet, [The Almighty](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=LfN2Wae-JKvv8wfkn6uQAQ) would definitely help you to get somewhere

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I done with the code but not getting expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `Db` you are using but I have an example using `Sql`.

Example:

You want to get the `Name` from the `Students` `Db`.

```
Dim dt As New DataTabale
Dim con As New SqlConnection("connection")
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM [Students] WHERE [Name] = @Name", con)
con.Open()

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox.Text

dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView.DataBind()
```

You can place this code on `Button`.

Ps. I view your the edit history of your code and I saw that you are using `Db`.

Answer (score -1):

```
   Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim query As String = TextBox1.Text

    Try
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = query
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("No results returned")
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: This will not work man. because I want to pass query in textbox. and at the time clicking i want to display result in datagridview

Comment: Edited String " " to TextBox1.Text